# Small form factor 3 V, one button on, off, or delay off timing circuit

Tags: switches, timer, switching

What is simplest or best solution, with the smallest form factor, for a circuit that operates on 3 VDC, turns on and off with one button, delays off with a preset time if the button is not pushed a second time, and draws no battery power when off? I understand what is simple or best for one might not be for another, so please forgive my choice of words, but I believe the meaning is clear.

Comment: We once needed exact same solution. After some searching, we decided to use microcontroller PIC10F222 to implement that feature with sleep mode control. If power consumption is critical issue, MSP430 may be better.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, with *"best"* you only mean *"smallest form factor"*. Or are there other criteria?

Comment: Hi, Yes by best I mean smallest. I solved the problem ussing a 555,3Res,1cap,1Relay,2Diodes and a switch. Others here suggested a microcontroller. I'm not familar with them, so I wonder if they require many connections such as grounding all unused pins, or still require transitors to accomplish the goal, if the end result might actually be using more surface area even though the controller itself is very small. Can anyone share the schematic or simplified dwg of the microcontroller solution? Thanks!